# how do i get the 1st, 1st&2nd and 1st,2nd &3rd characters from a string?

Tags: java

I have a string of numbers and I want to print the first, first and second, first,second and third characters from it. How do I approach this?

This code does not seem to be displaying it in my textview as the application just closes when run.

```
private char GetCharacters(String phoneNumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=phoneNumber.length();i++){

        data=phoneNumber.charAt(i);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SubstringExample.shtml

Comment: subString(0,1);subString(0,2);subString(0,3);

Comment: java subString(s,e); please do some research before posting questions. This is most basic java stuff, basically Java101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't your problem with it crashing that you are reading more numbers than the phone number has?

```
i<=phoneNumber.length();
```

As the index starts at 0 the number of elements is the same as `phoneNumber.length()-1`, so if you read the element at `phoneNumber.length()` you will get an error.

you function should be like this to function without crashing:

```
private char GetCharacters(String phoneNumber) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<phoneNumber.length();i++){

        data=phoneNumber.charAt(i);
    }
    return data;
}
```

as for getting the 1st, 1st & 2nd etc.  you should look into the [SubString](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=226) function, specifically:

```
phoneNumber.subString(0,1);
```

will get you the first character from the string

```
phoneNumber.subString(0,2);
```

will get you the second character from the string

and so on

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private char GetCharacters(String phoneNumber) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  for (int i=1;i<phoneNumber.length();i++){

    for (j=0;j<=i;j++){
      data=phoneNumber.charAt(j);
     }
  }
  return data;
}
```